# grep,how to search for exact pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

This was what I have tried

```
grep -n 'qtrain' *.m
```

But I got also

```
SKSC.m:195:model.qtrain = model.qtrainExtra(:,k-1);
SKSC.m:196:model.mqtrain = model.mqtrainExtra{k-1};
SKSC.m:197:model.sqtrain = model.sqtrainExtra{k-1};
```

How to get rid of the others?
I just want exact match with my pattern.

Comment: What is your expected output exactly? Give an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "exact pattern" you mean a complete line with only `qtrain` in it,
then use the `-x` flag:

```
grep -nx qtrain *.m
```

This will only match lines that contain exactly "qtrain" and nothing else.

---

If by "exact pattern" you mean to match "qtrain" but not "blahqtrain" or "qtrainblah", then you can use `-w` to match *whole words*:

```
grep -nw qtrain *.m
```

This will match only this line in your input:

> ```
> SKSC.m:195:model.qtrain = model.qtrainExtra(:,k-1);
> ```

Btw, here's another equivalent way using regular expressions:

```
grep -n '\<qtrain\>' *.m
```

From `man grep`:

> The  symbols  `\<`  and  `\>`  respectively  match  the empty string at the
>          beginning and end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do

```
grep -n '\.qtrain' *.m
```

To get anything with ".qtrain". Note that you have to escape the dot while grepping

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want it to return "qtrain"? If so, you probably want to use

`grep -no qtrain *.m`

If you were hoping it would only match lines in which "qtrain" was the only text, use

`grep -n ^qtrain$ *.m`